# How to diagnose dependency injection error in Angular Library

Tags: angular

I have an Angular library - all Angular 14.1.0, (which I have inherited), which includes a single project of UI elements, and then at the root level an "app" for testing the UI components.

One of the components of a popup messagebox, and one of the dependencies injected is `ngx-translate` (https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) which we use everywhere, no problems.

This morning the I could `ng serve` the test project and invoke this dialog. However after a small css modified, I reran it, and now I get an injection error. I have undone all my changes, and I still get it. I also deleted ALL `node_modules` and redid an `npm i` and everything came down, and when I build it all builds with no errors.

However, when I run and try to open this component, I get the following

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[n -> n -> tE -> tE -> tE]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for tE!
    NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[n -> n -> tE -> tE -> tE]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for tE!
        at cw.get (core.mjs:6364:27)
        at _w.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
        at _w.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
        at _w.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
        at CI (core.mjs:4775:33)
        at J (core.mjs:4779:42)
        at n.ɵfac [as factory] (ngx-translate-core.mjs:16:103)
        at _w.hydrate (core.mjs:6892:35)
        at _w.get (core.mjs:6780:33)
        at _w.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
        at xe (zone.js:1262:35)
        at zone.js:1169:21
        at zone.js:1185:37
        at nE (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
        at a (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
        at asyncToGenerator.js:32:1
        at new b (zone.js:1351:25)
        at asyncToGenerator.js:21:1
        at n.show (message-box.ts:92:49)
        at n.alert (message-box.ts:38:21)
```

So it is something to do with `ngx-translate-core` which is a peer dependency in the library (https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries), and is a dependency in the text project.

Also tried adding as a dev dependency in the library project, but made no difference.

The library module has

```
imports: [
    TranslateModule.forChild()
    ...
```

and the host test project module has

```
imports: [
  TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: () => new CustomNgxLoader(),
        },
        missingTranslationHandler: { provide: MissingTranslationHandler, useClass: CustomNgxMissingTranslationHandler },
        useDefaultLang: false
    }),
```

I am at an end, I have no idea why this has started happening or how to diagnose it.

I am running using `ng serve` but Angular tools reports I am running in production...

[image]

so I can't us it for anything.

When I look at each call in the error call stack, the code look minimized and incomprehensible.

How can I track this down?

Comment: Try to run it in developer mode, or click through the stack trace to get the value of the minimized variables. These variables are the key to diagnose the problem

Comment: I have actually been trying to run it in developer mode as we speak. I have no idea what the author has done to get it to run in prod! I am changing everything, but cannot get it to run in prod yet.

Comment: yeah I get what you say, but the bottom line is whatever you do, we need that minimized values, otherwise, it's impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a partial answer. My lesson here, is to make sure you are running in development mode!

I added

```
 "sourceMap": true,
 "optimization": false,
 "aot": false,
 "buildOptimizer": false,
```

to `architect/build/options` in `angular.json`  (so it must not default to these)

And now the error message was at least more meaningful...

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[TranslateService -> TranslateService -> TranslateStore -> TranslateStore -> TranslateStore]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateStore!
    NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[TranslateService -> TranslateService -> TranslateStore -> TranslateStore -> TranslateStore]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateStore!
        at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:6364:27)
        at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
        at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:6791:33)
```

So now I can see it is `TranslateStore` that is the problem, so now searching for this I find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672667/error-no-provider-for-translatestore), and adding the `providers:[TranslateStore ]` to the library module as suggested in the second answer fixed it for me (as far as I can see)

I have no idea why I get this now, where we never used to have to do this.

Comment: Note that for `inline code formatting`, you can use single backticks - three will work, but they are unnecessary.